# how to randomize order of questions in a quiz in python?

Tags: python

My coursework is about a game. So far I have programmed registration but on the second task it says to generate questions for a quiz, in a randomized order.

I have managed to make questions and the answers but, I don't know how to make them come up in a different order each time a new user plays. I have tried using the `random.randint()` code but I don't think I am using it correctly.

Comment: Have you checked `random.shuffle`?

Comment: You should probably show your existing solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `random.randint()` returns a list with integers put in a random number. What you really need is `random.shuffle()`. So you should make a list (I'll call it `questions`) because `random.shuffle` only works when there is a list in the parentheses. This should work because all you need to do is put your questions in the list, and let `random.shuffle()` do its magic:

```
questions = ['Question 1', 'Question 2', 'Question 3'] #You can add as many questions as you like
random.shuffle(questions)  #Mixes the items in "questions" into a random order
print questions[0]
print questions[1]
print questions[2]
```

And there are many different combinations/results you can get using `random.shuffle()` in this way. To also have the answers, same idea, except you need a `while` loop and know the order of the questions so you can choose the correct answer choices for each question. Still adding `random.shuffle()` for the answers:

```
questions = ['Question 1', 'Question 2', 'Question 3']
originals = [['Question 1', 'a1'], ['Question 2', 'b1'], ['Question 3', 'c1']]
answers = [['a1'], ['a2'], ['a3']], [['b1'], ['b2'], ['b3']], [['c1'], ['c2'], ['c3']]        #List of answers for each question
selected_answers = [] #Contains selected answers
random.shuffle(questions)
random.shuffle(answers[0])
random.shuffle(answers[1])
random.shuffle(answers[2])
question = 0
while question < 4:
    if questions[0] == 'Question 1':
        print 'Question 1'
        print answers[0][0], answers[0][1], answers[0][2]
        chosen = raw_input('Enter 1 for the first answer, 2 for the second answer and 3 for the third one.')
        selected_answers.append(chosen)
        del questions[0]
        question += 1
    elif questions[0] == 'Question 2':
        print 'Question 2'
        print answers[1][0], answers[1][1], answers[1][2]
        chosen = raw_input('Enter 1 for the first answer, 2 for the second answer and 3 for the third one.')
        selected_answers.append(chosen)
        del questions[0]
        question += 1
    elif questions[0] == 'Question 3':
        print 'Question 3'
        print answers[2][0], answers[2][1], answers[2][2]
        chosen = raw_input('Enter 1 for the first answer, 2 for the second answer and 3 for the third one.')
        selected_answers.append(chosen)
        del questions[0]
        question += 1
```

Using `originals`, you can check the answers from `selected_answers` with the correct one with its corresponding question. How you do that is your choice. This should be a base to help you.

Comment: Oh right thanks but, I also typed under each question an answer selection thing so the user would choose option 1, 2 or 3 for example. Does that mean I put your bit after all my question?

Comment: This answer is a very verbose way of saying "use `random.shuffle`."

Comment: Yes, it is @ron.rothman

Answer (score 0):

There is `choice` function in random module.
If the problem is choosing question randomly, you can simply use it.

```
import random
questions = ['Question1', 'Question2', 'Question3']
random.choice(questions)
```

Be careful, if `questions` is empty, `random.choice` raises `IndexError`