# How to use random.randint() without duplicating output? (CLOSED)

Tags: python

I am wanting to use random.randint() to make a random quiz using list. As of now my code works well but there are times where it will ask the user a question twice instead of randomising all questions. This happens only sometimes. How do I avoid this by only using random.randint? I can only use this and .del() as this is what I am taught in my course.

```
     import random
print("Welcome to Te Reo Maori Quiz!!!")
print("\nAnswer the questions with single Maori words")
Q = ['A challenge laid down in chant and dance:',
             'What is "Sun" in Maori:',
             'Something you eat to fill your belly:',
             'Type in the Maori word for "cave":',
             'Traditional Maori food cooked in an earth oven:',
             'Ma is white, whero is red, kakariki is green, pango is black. What else is black?:',
             'its getting ... in here, so take off all your clothes:',
             'What does Kia ora mean?:',
             'What does ka pai mean?:',
             'What does kei te peha koe mean?:',
             'What is the Maori phrase for "what is your name?:',
             'What does hikoi mean?:',
             'What is a waiata:',
             'What is the the Maori word for stomach?:',
             'What does mahi mean?',
             'What is the maori word for wait?:',
             'if something was nui, then it would be what?:',
             'What does Haere mai mean? (hint: it starts with "w"):',
             'What does nau mai mean?:',
             'What does tangi mean?:',
             ]

A = ['haka', 'ra', 'kai', 'ana', 'hangi', 'mangu', 'wera', 'hello', 'good', 'how are you', 'ko wai to ingoa', 'walk',
'song', 'puku', 'work', 'taihoa', 'big', 'welcome', 'welcome', 'funeral' 
]


points = 0
current = 0 
quiz = 0 

while (quiz < 5):

    question = Q[current]
    answer = A[current]

    question = input("\nQ" + str(quiz + 1) + ". " + Q[current])

    if question.lower() == answer.lower(): 
        points = points + 20 #adds points if the answer is correct
        current = current + 2
        print("Correct Answer!") 

    else:
        print("Incorrect answer. The correct answer is:", A[current]) 
        ###points = points - 10
        ###current = current + 2
    #quiz = quiz + 1

    ###if points < 0:
        ###points = 0

print("\nEnd of Quiz.")
print("Your score: %", points, sep = "")
```

I expect my code to produce 5 random questions at every iteration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to randomize order of questions in a quiz in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30970070/how-to-randomize-order-of-questions-in-a-quiz-in-python)

Comment: Possibly also similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755538/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-random-numbers-without-duplicates

Comment: put in an if statement to check if its choosing a question that's already been chosen and choose again if so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a list of random numbers without duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755538/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-random-numbers-without-duplicates)

Comment: You should reduce the pool by the element you drew on each iteration, otherwise your routine will decrease in efficiency. Imagine drawing 99 elements from a list of 100 without repetition. If you draw from range(100) and then always check if you already drew this number it will take you more and more time to draw a new valid number. Do `samples = range(len(Q)); random.shuffle(samples)` and then whenever you draw a new element do `Q[samples.pop()]` - problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to avoid duplication in while loop.

```
Q = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
while len(Q)!= 0:
    x = random.randint(0,len(Q)-1)
    print(Q[x])
    Q = [v for v in Q if v != Q[x]]
```

---

A only `random.randint()` allowed solution.

```
import random
print("Welcome to Te Reo Maori Quiz!!!")
print("\nAnswer the questions with single Maori words")
Q = ['A challenge laid down in chant and dance:',
             'What is "Sun" in Maori:',
             'Something you eat to fill your belly:',
             'Type in the Maori word for "cave":',
             'Traditional Maori food cooked in an earth oven:',
             'Ma is white, whero is red, kakariki is green, pango is black. What else is black?:',
             'its getting ... in here, so take off all your clothes:',
             'What does Kia ora mean?:',
             'What does ka pai mean?:',
             'What does kei te peha koe mean?:',
             'What is the Maori phrase for "what is your name?:',
             'What does hikoi mean?:',
             'What is a waiata:',
             'What is the the Maori word for stomach?:',
             'What does mahi mean?',
             'What is the maori word for wait?:',
             'if something was nui, then it would be what?:',
             'What does Haere mai mean? (hint: it starts with "w"):',
             'What does nau mai mean?:',
             'What does tangi mean?:',
             ]

A = ['haka', 'ra', 'kai', 'ana', 'hangi', 'mangu', 'wera', 'hello', 'good', 'how are you', 'ko wai to ingoa', 'walk',
'song', 'puku', 'work', 'taihoa', 'big', 'welcome', 'welcome', 'funeral' ]

CQ = Q[:]
points = 0
quiz = 0

while (quiz < 5):
    x = random.randint(0, len(CQ)-1)
    print(str(quiz + 1) + ". " + CQ[x])

    UA = input("\n " )
    if A[Q.index(CQ[x])].lower() == UA.lower():
        points = points + 20 #adds points if the answer is correct
        print("Correct Answer!") 

    else:
        print("Incorrect answer. The correct answer is:", A[Q.index(CQ[x])])        

    quiz += 1
    del CQ[x]


print("\nEnd of Quiz.")
print("Your score: ", points)
```

---

Yet this solution contains knowledge about:

- a copy of a list `CQ = Q[:]`
- find the index of an item in a list `Q.index(CQ[x])`

Answer (score 0):

Just shuffle your questions, and then iterate through them:

```
import random
Q = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

random.shuffle(Q)
print(Q)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reduce the pool by the element you drew on each iteration, otherwise your routine will decrease in efficiency.

Imagine drawing 99 elements from a list of 100 without repetition. If you draw from `range(100)` every time and then check if you already drew this number before, it will take you more and more time to draw a new valid number.

Simply create a random sequence of indices:

```
import random
samples = range(len(Q))
random.shuffle(samples)
```

and then whenever you want a new random question, remove an element from the list of indices and get the corresponding question:

```
Q[samples.pop()]
```

You are sure to not draw any question twice and you do not alter the order of the list of questions. Problem solved.